# Comando SQL funciona no SQL SHELL, mas não funciona no node (pg) (provavelmente algo relacionado à acentuação)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express.js, codificação-de-caracteres, collation

**BANCO DE DADOS** 
Tenho esse banco de dados:
[image: Banco de dados chamado exemplo]
Nele eu tenho essa tabela: 
[image: Tabela pessoas dentro do banco de dados exemplo]
Nela tenho esses dados: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**NODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

// cors config // origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// Database
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
var pool = null;

pool = new Pool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'exemplo',
    port: '5432'
});

// Routes
const { Router } = require('express');
const routes = Router();

routes.get('/pessoas', async function(req, res) {
  const response = await pool.query("select * from pessoas where disciplina = 'Matemática'");
  res.status(200).json({response: response.rows});
},);

app.use(routes);

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port);
```

**PROBLEMA** 
Ao executar, "SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE disciplina = 'Matemática', aparece isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Ou seja, nenhum problema até aí, funcionou perfeitamente. PORÉM, ao abrir a rota "/pessoas" (código do Node acima): 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
nenhum resultado é retornado. Mas se eu escolher, por exemplo, "Geografia" em vez de "Matemática", que por acaso a única diferença é acento agudo:

```
routes.get('/pessoas', async function(req, res) {
  const response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE disciplina = 'Geografia'");
  res.status(200).json({response: response.rows});
},);
```

Vejam:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**FIM** 
Por favor, se souberem resolver isso, me ajudem. Já procurei resposta em város lugares e tentei várias coisas (mudei o CLIENT_ENCODING, mudei o CType, cheguei a mexer no Collate, etc.). Acredito que seja algum detalhe bobo do qual não estou consciente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depois que eu instalei no servidor esse problema parou de acontecer.

Answer (score 0):

Substitui o trecho do código abaixo:

```
routes.get('/pessoas', async function(req, res) {    
 const response = await pool.query("select * from pessoas where disciplina = 'Matemática'");    
 res.status(200).json({response: response.rows}); 
});
```

Por esse daqui:

```
routes.get('/pessoas', async function(req, res) {    
  const response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE disciplina = $1', ['Matemática']);      
  res.status(200).json({response: response.rows});  
});
```

Consideração importante:

Sempre utilize queries com valores parametrizados, ou seja, não insira os valores direto no comando SQL da query para evitar ataques de SQL Injection.

[Link para a documentação](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) do node-postgres.

Comment: Verdade, usar queries sem parametrizar os valores é arriscado, mas esse exemplo acima é apenas uma simplificação do projeto real, nele eu tomei essa precaução. Meu problema já foi resolvido, não entendi o que aconteceu, mas quando fiz o deploy pro servidor as acentuações funcionaram.

Comment: Apenas localmente que não tava funcionando, mas ainda não tenho certeza vou realizar alguns testes.